# Why does density decrease most above Mach 0.3, and not as much below Mach 0.3?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Why does density decrease more above Mach 0.3, and not as much below Mach 0.3? From what I've heard, it isn't a linear relationship but why is that? Asked differently, what makes it a non linear relationship?

Thanks!

[Link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150958/discussion-between-camille-goudeseune-and-wyatt) to chat room of this question.

Also, the last paragraph of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/is-my-understanding-of-density-speed-correct) question has my guess of why the density doesn't change much below Mach ~0.3. It might be useful to see where I'm coming from.

Comment: Some reading [here](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/normal.html).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Interesting concepts in there. Thanks

Comment: Q.1 asks what it does.  Q.2 mentions the definition of nonlinearity, and then asks why.  Q.3 asks the *opposite* of Q.1.  The third paragraph asks yet another question.  Help!  Use *fewer* words, not more.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune hmm could you quote which question is asking something opposite? I'd like to improve what's wrong with this question. I do see something that does kind ask the opposite of what I said, so I'll change it now. Any better?

Comment: Your edit just now improved the question, thanks!  But if you can edit it down even farther so it asks just a single question, that would help a ton.  Find the one best way to phrase the question, and leave it at that.  Repeating with variations is useful for poetry and theology, but in the hard sciences it's only confusing.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Oh okay, so do you suggest that I ask a separate question for the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs?

Comment: Ask one question per stack-exchange-question.  How you do that is up to you!

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Oh okay, gotcha. I will definitely do that, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150958/discussion-between-camille-goudeseune-and-wyatt).

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, okay, sent you a message there.

Comment: Take the [tour] and look into [how to ask a good question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

When you combine the equations for [isentropic flow](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/isentrop.html)
you can plot
"density compared to density at zero speed, M=0", i.e. $\rho / \rho_0$, as a function of M.

Anderson's [*Fundamentals of Aerodynamics*](https://archive.org/details/FundamentalsOfAerodynamics5thEdition)
[presents](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/threshhold-compressible-flow-ma-0-3.940081/) that as
$\rho_0 / \rho = (1+ \frac {\gamma -1}{2} M^2)^{\frac{1} {\gamma-1}}$ with $\gamma = 1.4$ for air  (page 567, eq. 8.43).

Inverting,
$\rho / \rho_0 = (1+ \frac {\gamma -1}{2} M^2)^{\frac{1} {1-\gamma}}$.

I've copied a [plot](http://www.aerodynamics4students.com/gas-dynamics-and-supersonic-flow/gasdynamics_w.php?page=1&)
of this below, but you can calculate it yourself if you like.  The red curve shows that M = 0.3 isn't magical.  (At M=0.3, the density ratio is 0.956.)  It's just a convenient, practically useful threshold for everyday calculations.

Why isn't the red curve a straight line?  Because these equations have proven to be a useful, accurate, predictive model of fluid flow in many fields, and these equations are nonlinear.  You could replace them with linear ones if you liked, but the calculations you'd make with them would be less accurate.

[image]

Anderson's own plot, p. 573 fig. 8.6, agrees:
[image]